# Configurable product's product options add to cart "Please specify the product's option(s)."

Tags: ce-1.9.2.2

I have this strange issue while adding certain child product of configurable. It gives "Please choose specific options (size / colour) of the product and then click the Saved Lists icon." message which is basically "Please specify the product's option(s)." message.

This is custom size attribute with 480+ options.

I am curious whether the code flow got lost in too many filtrations ? I have debugged up to `Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Configurable.php` >> method `getProductByAttributes` >> line number 503 in the attached core file. It gets lost from above line number.

I'll be very thankful for your great help to know what's wrong.

[Here is the product url](https://mimstore.com.au/dr-comfort-lycra-black-flute-women-s-merry-jane-dress-shoes.html)

Options: Width = Wide, Size = 10 (and 6)

The child product has enough qty (more than 10)

This is a live site where requires login to see the price and add to cart so I have created a video walkthrough to show frontend and backend to explain the issue [here](https://www.useloom.com/share/2bc1046ae3a04f1dbf2338ee27f1dd48).

Here is the portion of code where I've reached so far of [Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Configurable](https://pastebin.com/gh3Nkfet)

```
public function getProductByAttributes($attributesInfo, $product = null)
{
    if (is_array($attributesInfo) && !empty($attributesInfo)) {
        $productCollection = $this->getUsedProductCollection($product)->addAttributeToSelect('name');

        foreach ($attributesInfo as $attributeId => $attributeValue) {
            $productCollection->addAttributeToFilter($attributeId, $attributeValue);
        }

        $productObject = $productCollection->getFirstItem();
        if ($productObject->getId()) {


            return $productObject;
        }

        /**
         * Size option's value get lost by here
         * So it returns null
         */

        //Mage::log($attributesInfo, null, 'debug-product-options.txt');

        foreach ($this->getUsedProducts(null, $product) as $productObject) {
            $checkRes = true;
            foreach ($attributesInfo as $attributeId => $attributeValue) {
                $code = $this->getAttributeById($attributeId, $product)->getAttributeCode();

                if ($productObject->getData($code) != $attributeValue) {
                    $checkRes = false;
                }
            }



            if ($checkRes) {
                return $productObject;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```